# providing dependency in root module for a library module

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, provider

scenario:

all i want to do is provide the sword (implements IWeapon) that is defined in the root app to warrior component through DI.  where warrior component is defined in a library project and the parameter that warrior component accept is of type IWeapon which is also defined in the warrior library project

Update:  i have everything compiling by doing the following, however when in the browser console it complains 'no providerfound for Weapon':

Warrior Library Project:

```
export class Weapon {
 strike(): Promise<Pain> { return null; }
}
```

WarriorComponent construction(private weapon: Weapon) { ...

WarriorModule has an empty providers array.

I build and package the warrior module and npm install it in RootApplication
Root application has 
Sword service as such:

```
@Injectable()
export class Sword extends Weapon { 
     strike(): Promise<Pain> { 
         return "a lot `of pain";
    } 
 }
```

Root application's app module has the provider defined as such:

```
providers: [ { provide: Weapon, useClass: Sword } ]
```

Update: if i modify the root app.module's constructor as such:
constructor(private weapon: Weapon)
and if set a break point in that constructor then i can see in debug tools that weapon is successfully getting resolved by the DI however, in the Weapon module/component DI isn't able to resolve that dependency.  That is very weird.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example? Either through a tool like https://stackblitz.com/ or by providing some more complete code snippets directly in your post?

Comment: `Weapon` should have `@Injectable` as it is in `provide` of  ` provide: Weapon, useClass: Sword` . Provide a demo code as suggested by Jack